# Calling an action in ArticlesController, from CommentsController - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### The situation:

I have something like the following:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :turns

   def calculate_score
      #return score of all turns played so far
   end       
end

class Turn < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :game
end
```

... with corresponding controllers. (this isn't exactly what I have, but my question is very general. The question title shows another similar situation)

When I am in **/game/:id** (the show action), I display all turns, and have AJAX edit-in-place to update any turns. Updating a turn calls the **update** method of *TurnsController*.

#### The question:

How can I, from *TurnsController*, call an action in the *GameController* after a turn is updated?

I need an action called "turn_updated" in *GameController* to check all turns and perform manipulations on the collection game.turns .

Thanks!

PS: Clearly I am new to Rails, so I can't be more specific because I am not exactly sure of how to phrase my question, or of what is possible.

---

#### Update:

Thanks for the answers so far.

I have been using a redirect_to, but my problem with that is that **update** is an AJAX call. It needs to **render :text => @turn.value** in some conditions, and **redirect_to** in others. Since it's an AJAX call, redirect_to replaces the div that showed the turn value with the entire contents of the new address.

I am trying things along these lines now:

```
#turn update action
def update
   url = url_for(:controller => 'games', :action => 'turn_updated', :id => @turn.game_id)
   render :partial => 'shared/redirect.js.erb', :locals => {:url => url}
end
```

and the partial is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace(<%= url %>);</script>
```

I am getting closer with this, but it seems somewhat flimsy...
For instance, if I replace the partial's JS with *alert("Works!");* it executes the alert, but the redirect doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to rethink your approach here. Controllers aren't meant to communicate to each other. If you want to do something after a turn has been updated, make it a method on the model and call it from the *TurnsController*. You could even add an after_save callback to the model, but be aware that callbacks can lead to mayhem, especially if they're complicated.

Think carefully which method goes on which object. Where does it belong? Controllers should be fairly straight forward: Get a resource and show it (for GET requests), or perform one action and redirect back to a GET page. If the stuff you want to do doesn't belong on the model either, make a service class or a different model.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Marked this as answer, because I did need to rethink things. I ended up simply calling the GameController action directly, and handling everything there.

Answer (score 0):

In a controller, use a redirect:

```
def my_turn_action
  # ...
  redirect_to :controller => :game, :action => :turn_updated and return
end
```

In a view (i.e., if you just want a link to a different controller):

```
<%= link_to :controller => :game, :action => :turn_updated %>
```

Comment: Thanks Platinum Azure. Redirects were causing me headaches because I was using AJAX calls, so redirects had to be done by rendering a JS redirect partial.

Comment: @AdrianoFerrari: Thanks for replying. I didn't see you were using AJAX, sorry.